# Get StartsWith value

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get the string value of the startsWith. Currently, its output is boolean.
How do I display the string instead of True/False in my SQL database?

Sample txt file Data:

```
1238536666661563
5641516635635556
4565468564635161
7945652594517129
7895421634456144
```

what I want to be stored in my SQL Database table:

```
1238536666661563 - "Title"
4565468564635161 - "Subtitle"
7895421634456144 - "Body"
```

Updated code - this still displayes boolean. i want the full line that starts with eg."123"

```
Protected Sub Read(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
Dim records = File.ReadLines(Server.MapPath("~/File.txt")).
     Where(Function(line) line.StartsWith("123")).
     Select(Function(line) MyData.Parse(line))

Insert(records)
End Sub

  Public Sub Insert(Records As IEnumerable(Of MyData))
Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO Test (Title, Subtitle, Body) VALUES (@Title, @Subtitle, @Body)"
Using con As New SqlConnection(con), 
      cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)  
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Subtitle", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Body", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)      

    con.Open()
    For Each record As MyData In Records
        cmd.Parameters("@Title").Value = record.Title
        cmd.Parameters("@Subtitle").Value = record.Subtitle
        cmd.Parameters("@Body").Value = record.Body

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at the `Substring` method of [System.String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Note that you should keep the open and close of the database outside of the loop reading file records. Also you should not open the database unless the file name is as you want it to be. You could use substring or startsWith. Go to the debugger and test.

Comment: Hi, I have taken your comments onboard and Ihave edited my code. my code still returns boolean. I am not looking for a substring of the lines but to return each line that starts with eg."123"

Answer (score 1):

```
Protected Sub Read(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/File.txt"))
    For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
        Dim Title As String = lines(i)
        If Title.StartsWith("123") Then
           Insert(Title)
        End
    Next
End Sub


Public Sub Insert(Title As String)
    Using con As New SqlConnection(con)    
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Test (Title) VALUES (@Title)")
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", Title)

            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: This works for one parameter but when I add in multiple they are not unique to each column. each column displays all starts with cases

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, and also make the code **quite a bit faster and more memory efficient**.

```
Protected Sub Read(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim lines = File.ReadLines(Server.MapPath("~/File.txt")).
         Where(Function(line) line.StartsWith("123"))

    Insert(lines)
End Sub

Public Sub Insert(Titles As IEnumerable(Of String))
    Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO Test (Title) VALUES (@Title)"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(con), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)

        ' Use the actual column type and length here
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)        

        con.Open()
        For Each title As String In Titles
            cmd.Parameters("@Title").Value = title
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Notice `ReadLines()` vs `ReadAllLines()`, which will save memory, and notice how the `Insert()` method now accepts the entire set, so we only need one command/connection in a much tighter loop.

But I also see a comment on another answer about needing more columns. In that case, you should also **define a class** to encapsulate the columns you need, with a property for each column. Then you add a Static/Shared method to the class to parse the data from a string input. This assumes each line in the file is a complete record:

```
Public Class MyData
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Field2 As DateTime
    ' ...
    Public Property FieldN As String
    ' Of course, use better names than this

    Public Shared Function Parse(input As String) As MyData
         Return New MyData() With {
              ' Use things like RegEx, String functions,
              ' or CSV/JSON parsers here to get the 
              ' fields you need from the string
         }
    End Function
End Class
```

Once you have this class, the earlier `Read()` and `Insert()` code changes like this:

```
Protected Sub Read(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim records = File.ReadLines(Server.MapPath("~/File.txt")).
         Where(Function(line) line.StartsWith("123")).
         Select(Function(line) MyData.Parse(line))

    Insert(records)
End Sub

Public Sub Insert(Records As IEnumerable(Of MyData))
    Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO Test (Title, Field2, FieldN) VALUES (@Title, @Field2, @FieldN)"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(con), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)

        ' Use the actual column type and length here
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)  
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Field2", SqlDbType.DateTime)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FieldN", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20)      

        con.Open()
        For Each record As MyData In Records
            cmd.Parameters("@Title").Value = record.Title
            cmd.Parameters("@Field2").Value = record.Field2
            cmd.Parameters("@FieldN").Value = record.FieldN

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

If each line in the file is NOT a complete record, and records are spread over several lines, you'll need to change the `Read()` method to first know where the records start and stop, and be able to pass a complete record's worth of data at a time to your `Parse()` or `Create()` method.

It's also very likely the file is in a format for which there is an existing generic parser (like INI, JSON, XML, etc), and in this case **always use the existing parser**. An existing parser will tend to have fewer bugs (especially around edge cases). It will be *less work* for you to get working, even if it can be intimidating to get it set up at first. They will result in less code for you to write and maintain. And they will also tend to be *much faster and more efficient*.

---

Based on comments, we're starting to get somewhere:

```
Public Class MyData
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Subtitle As String = ""
    Public Property Body As String = ""
End Class
```

```
Public Iterator Function ReadFile(filePath As String) As IEnumerable(Of MyData)
    Dim currentRecord As MyData = Nothing
    Dim lines = File.ReadLines(filePath)
    For Each line As String In Lines
        If line.StartsWith("123") Then 'New Record
             If currentRecord IsNot Nothing Then Yield currentRecord

             currentRecord = new MyData() With {.Title = line}
        End If

        If line.StartsWith("456") Then currentRecord.Subtitle += line
        If line.StartsWith("789") Then currentRecord.Body += line
    Next line
    If currentRecord IsNot Nothing Then Yield currentRecord 
End Function
```

```
Protected Sub Read(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Insert(ReadFile(Server.MapPath("~/File.txt")))
End Sub
```

```
Public Sub Insert(Records As IEnumerable(Of MyData))
    Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO Test (Title, Subtitle, Body) VALUES (@Title, @Subtitle, @Body)"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(con), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)

        ' Use the actual column type and length here
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)  
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Subtitle", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Body", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1)      

        con.Open()
        For Each record As MyData In Records
            cmd.Parameters("@Title").Value = record.Title
            cmd.Parameters("@Subtitle").Value = record.Subtitle
            cmd.Parameters("@Body").Value = record.Body

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. YES I am looking to have multiple parameters eg.
 where title starts with "123",
 where subtitle starts with "456",
 where body starts with "789" etc...

 when I run your code I get an error "Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.String]' to type 'System.String[]'"

Comment: @Martha None of my code calls for an array. Are you sure you defined the `Insert()` function the way I suggested? Of maybe you left the `As String()` type on the `Dim lines` part, instead of letting type inference work.  Remember, `File.ReadLines()` **does not return an array**.

Comment: This error occurs on the line: Insert(lines). it only occurs when I use the  .Select(Function(line) MyData.Parse(line)) line. ur code without using the Public Shared Function Parse works perfectly

Comment: It sounds like you still have `Dim lines as String() =` instead of just `Dim lines =`. The former is not correct, because this does not result in an array. But you may want to edit your question to include the updated code.

Comment: I have the line  Dim lines = File.ReadLines. I think there is an issue with the class in my code. as without it, the code returns lines starting with 123 perfectly. I will carry out some more debugging and post my code. Ps. thanks you for your continued help :)

Comment: Is it possible for you to give an example of the Public Class MyData as I think the code I have  is incorrect: Public Class MyData
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Subtitle As String
    Public Property Body As String

    Public Shared Function Parse(input As String) As MyData
         Return New MyData() With {.Subtitle = input.StartsWith("456"), .Body = input.StartsWith("789")
              
         }
    End Function
End Class

Comment: `StartsWith()` results in a boolean True/False value, **not a string.** You haven't shared enough information yet about what your data actually looks like for us to give you a better answer than that.

Comment: I have added sample data to my question. and to clarify I am looking for ways to display the full line of data in text file that starts with eg.("123")

Comment: How will you spot in the file where one full record stops and the next starts?

Comment: Each line is a new record that needs to be checked

Comment: @Martha, That's not generally how this works. Title, Subtitle, and Body are each on different lines, but as a group should belong with one record.

Comment: I have one text file which contains many lines. I want to read each line. if any line starts with "123" I want that full line (eg.1238536666661563)to be stored in my SQL table under the name "Title". If any Line starts with "456"  I want that full line (eg.4565468564635161)to be stored in my SQL table under the name "Subtitle". If any line starts with "789"  I want that full line (eg.7895421634456144)to be stored in  my SQL table under the name "Body". Sorry for the confusion I hope this clears it up

Comment: Yes, I understand that. And your table has (at least) three columns: Title, Subtitle, and Body, and for a given set of a data you should have the Title, Subtitle, and Body in the same row. That's one record. And the file may have more than one set like this. You need to know where one set stops and the other starts.

Comment: Every line belongs to either title, subtitle, or body. once the next line starts with "123" that is a new set of data (but still in the same txt file). I am unsure as to your question or how this will help me get each line value that starts with "123" and not displayed in boolean format

Comment: So you'll never have a line starting with 564, as in the sample in the question? And you'll never have more than one body line for the same title?

Comment: Yes I will potentially. however, it will be attached to something else eg. Closing Statement. and is not relevant to lines starting with "123"

Comment: Updated the answer with new code at the end

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a list of matching lines, Linq is very good at that sort of thing.

```vb
Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~/File.txt"))
Dim matching = lines.Where(Function(line) line.StartsWith("123"))
```

This will create an enumerable sequence of lines that start with "123".  If you want to do additional processing, you could chain a `Select` onto this, e.g.

```vb
Dim matching = lines.Where(Function(line) line.StartsWith("123")) _
    .Select(Function(item) PostProcess(item))
```

(or I think you could use `AddressOf` for a case like this where you just want to directly call a function, vs. doing simple processing inline)